# Nativescript: Where to store navigation?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Using Nativescript, where is the navigation in the SideDrawer stored? Should it be stored in application settings as a json string, or just loaded with an api call everytime it's needed?

Answer (score 0):

every time you call [$navigateTo](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/) or [similar](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_frame_.frame#navigate) [navigation](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-navigation) strategy, you generate a kind of navigation entry (varying depending of your nativescript flavour) and this is used to tell to where back button should go if pressed.

Please note you might set [clearHistory](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation) in order to take rid of the navigation entries stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Frame (Core / Vue) / page-router-outlet (Angular) as root for drawer content, the navigation history should be taken care by default.

Hitting the back button will automatically take you to previous page on the topmost frame's navigation stack.